# Переконвертировать строку в дату

Tags: php

Есть такая строка

```
23.05.1988
```

Как переконвертировать в php в дату формата

```
1988-05-23
```

что бы записать в Mysql потом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как в ответе говорили, можно в SQL запросе сразу, но если именно хочется в PHP тогда так:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('23.05.1988'));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Как переконвертировать в php в дату формата

Зачем? Отдайте свою строку MySQL как есть, он разберётся:

```
INSERT INTO table (             date_field             , other_fields)
VALUES            (STR_TO_DATE('12.06.2017','%d.%m.%Y'), other_values);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = new DateTime('23.05.1988');
$date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score -2):

```
str_replace(".", "-", "12.06.2017");
```

Comment: А то, что нужно поставить год вперёд, а число назад - оно типа само сделается?